# Expected values, and probabilities using exponential distributions

Tags: statistics

Let X be a random variable that is defined as time until the commercials after a TV show starts. X is assumed to have an exponential distribution with mean given as 12 mins.

a) compute the expected value of 
2x + 10 (by integration)

b) find the probability that first 15 minutes will be commercial free.

C) using the pdf function, derive the cdf for exponential distribution.

I was told by my professor that i didn't even need to integrate part A but when she used that method i don't know what to do next.

I'm just confused on this question in general

Answer (score 2):

First you said the random variable is called (capital) $X,$ but then in part $(a)$ you called it (lower-case) $x.$ That is an incorrect usage. Without this distinction one could not understand expressions like $\Pr(X\ge x),$ and there are a bunch of other things like that.

For part $(a)$ you can say $\operatorname E(2X+5) = 2\operatorname E(X)+5 = 2\cdot12+5.$

For parts $(b)$ and $(c),$ I would want to know specifically what information you are relying on and at what points you ran into something that you didn't know how to do.

Comment: Sorry mistake it is Captial X

Comment: The answer for the first part is apparently 34

Comment: They broke it up into two integrals apparently which was the alternative

Comment: Integral from 0 to infinity 2x lamda (e)^-lamda x

Comment: + integral of zero to infinity of. 10 * lamda (e)^ -lamda x dx

Comment: For part $(b):$ $$ \Pr(X>15) = \int_{15}^\infty e^{-x/12}\, \frac{dx}{12} = \int_{15/12}^\infty e^{-u}\, du = \left. \vphantom{\frac11} -e^{-u} \right|_{u\,:=\,15/12}^\infty = e^{-15/12} = e^{-5/4} = \cdots $$